# Laravel mutual methods for many models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I added a method to one of my models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function ($model) {
            //log $model or maybe do something more complex here
        });
    }
}
```

And i wish to extend the same behaviour to many other models. Copy pasting this doesent seem like a good idea because if something changes i dont want to change it in different places. What is the best solution to write this only once and get the same behaviour to multiple models?

Comment: If you haven’t already, create a base model class that extends eloquent and when you create models, they will generally extend the Model, thus, extending any functions you commonly require. I’m away from a PC to write the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traits are built for that. Write once and use on all classes.

Create a trait in app/Traits/MyTraitName.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;

trait MyTraitName
{

    public function someName() {
        // TO DO;
    }

}
```

and then just import it on top of any model class for example User:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use App\Traits\MyTraitName;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, MyTraitName;

 ..............
```

The difference between extending a class and making a trait is that when you make a trait that function is already written and it's automatically used the same way on every model, and extending from some base class is better if that function is not going to be the same for every Model.